# Why does FB crop the image you give it for the Like button?

Tags: facebook-like

No matter what image I specify with

```
<meta property='og:image' content='http://www.mysite.com/images/img1.jpg' />
```

Facebook crops the image, often cutting off peoples' heads, as in the example below. Is there a way to keep FB from cropping the image?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Can you point to a example so SO users can see this issue in action?

Comment: That's what I did in the figure above. The large image on the left is the image that is actually on the web page.  The src for this image was given to the og:image specification and what got put onto the vistor's facebook page is shown in the smaller image on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing cfs parameter, can you add to your page:

```
<meta property="og:image:width" content="180" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="110" />
```

Please replace 180 and 110 by your image size values.

Answer (score 1):

This scaling comes from a parameter generated by Facebook in URL's image.

This is an example of a generated image:
https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQAzfOH9x1vWvGLf&w=154&h=154&url=http%3A%2F%2Fshailan.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fwordpress-facebook-thumbnails.jpg&cfs=1&upscale

To reach your goal you need to change parameter **cfs=1** by **cfs=0** in above URL.

You will obtain something like:
https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQAzfOH9x1vWvGLf&w=154&h=154&url=http%3A%2F%2Fshailan.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fwordpress-facebook-thumbnails.jpg&cfs=0&upscale

I presume facebook allows to do it without manual intervention such as javascrit edit or so.
I will have a look to facebook API to check if you can do it by adding a og parameter or something like it.